# 'hibernate.dialect' not set even after setting it in properties

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate created a simple hibernate application in which I'm trying to create a session factory object my code goes as follows:

```
public class Hibernateutil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
 }
```

this is where im trying to get session from factory and trying to save/commit an entity

```
@Repository
public class StudentRepository1 {


    SessionFactory factory = Hibernateutil.getSessionFactory();

    Session currentSession =factory.getCurrentSession();

    //do something
}
```

application.yml file:

```
# Details for our datasource
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
# Hibernate properties
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
      #current_session_context_class: thread
    show-sql: false
    hibernate.ddl-auto: 
#application properties
  application:
    name: hibernate_demo
server:
  port: 10091
```

and the error im getting:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted`
```

dependencies of my project:

```
dependencies {
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.1.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.2.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.2'

}
```

`

im using postgres 9.5

please help me out i have wasted a week trying some workarounds present on many websites but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you're creating the `SessionFactory`.

If your `spring-boot` application has `spring-boot-autoconfigure` on the classpath, then all you need to make sure is that you have Hibernate and all the needed dependencies on the classpath as well in order for it to automatically create an `EntityManagerFactory` or `SessionFactory` bean.  This is all handled by `spring-boot-autoconfigure`, see its documentation should you need to customize the default behavior.

If your `spring-boot` application does not include `spring-boot-autoconfigure` on the classpath, then you'll need to manually configure the necessary `EntityManagerFactory` or `SessionFactory` beans in your spring configuration; again the spring documentation covers this quite extensively.

In a spring-based application, there is really no need for your `HibernateUtil` class here, which is the crux of the problem.  Spring's dependency injection can handle providing your classes with the appropriate instance of an `EntityManager` or `SessionFactory` as needed, although I generally suggest using JPA here.

So inside your repository class, you'd do this

```
@Repository
public class MyFancyRepositoryImpl implements MyFancyRepository {
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public void doSomethingCool(TheEntity entity) {
    entityManager.persist( entity );

    // should you need access to the raw Hibernate session, unwrap 
    final Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );
    // now you can use the `Session` as needed/
  }
}
```

This means your `HibernateUtil` class can be removed as its entirely unnecessary.